# Angular download file from server

Tags: java, angularjs, playframework-2.0

I have a application that has java on play framework as backend and angular as frontend.

I have an end point in java that will show a pdf when accessing the endpoint. However I will prefer to use angular to download the file.

Java backend is something like this

```
response().setContentType("application/pdf");
response().setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename='report.pdf'");
return ok(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
```

The angular frontend is something like this

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'report/2'}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
    var str = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(data));
    hiddenElement.href = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + str;
    hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
    hiddenElement.download = 'myFile.pdf';
    hiddenElement.click();  
})
```

However, when I downloaded the file, the content is not there anymore. Not sure if it's an decoding issue.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What does "the content is not there anymore" mean?  Are you getting an error?  What is the value of `data` in the success callback?

Comment: Have you found any answer?

Comment: Answered nere : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35205589/how-to-get-angularjs-blob-to-download-pdf